# Is that possible to turn off the camera indicator led (iSight) when capturing on mac osx?

Tags: macos, camera

Problem Situation:
I have a program which open the iMacs' iSight camera for recording (used by government). I got a tutorial and made my version via QTKit, while the camera's green indicator led is always alerting the user that you are being captured~~~

Is that possible to turn off the camera indicator led (iSight) when capturing on mac osx?

This program will never be used by citizens.

Any Guide, Appreciated.

Comment: (In Europe there is a legal requirement to make it apparent when a picture is being taken or a video is being made.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. The iSight camera LED is controlled by the camera hardware, and is always lit while the camera is active.

Comment: Er, Thank you telling me this.